# How to set up orbit and camera values to move like a human walking

Tags: three.js, camera, orbit

I have a scene with an object and I want to move like a human walking inside my scene, that means:
minPolarAngle and maxPolarAngle stay "locked" and
stop my movemente when I reach camera.lookAt position

I put the same value in minPolarAngle and maxPolarAngle but when I reach the camera.lookAt position value the orbit changes rotation like climbing a hill. It makes any sense?

As I said before, I just need a "walking" feeling but do not how to set up orbit and camera values.

Comment: Seems, you need another type of controls: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=controls#misc_controls_pointerlock

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, I did not realize that pointerlock exists.